# Parse Embedded JSON with SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift2, swifty-json

I have been at this a while but can't get the parsing just righty. I am trying to parse This json file:

```
{
 "order_history" : [ {
   "items" : [ {
    "id" : 284,
    "created" : [ 2016, 5, 26, 5, 27, 53 ],
    "updated" : [ 2016, 5, 27, 0, 31, 10 ],
    "sku" : "10-10-08-050",
    "name" : "Product one of set one",
    "description" : "",
    "quantity" : 1.0,
    "price" : 2000.0,
    "total" : 2000.0,
    "tax" : null,
    "discount" : null
}, {
  "id" : 285,
  "created" : [ 2016, 5, 26, 5, 27, 53 ],
  "updated" : [ 2016, 5, 27, 0, 31, 10 ],
  "sku" : "10-22-12-247",
  "name" : "Product 2 of set 1",
  "description" : "",
  "quantity" : 1.0,
  "price" : 2300.0,
  "total" : 2300.0,
  "tax" : null,
  "discount" : null
}, {
  "id" : 286,
  "created" : [ 2016, 5, 26, 5, 27, 53 ],
  "updated" : [ 2016, 5, 27, 0, 31, 10 ],
  "sku" : "10-22-12-249",
  "name" : "Product 3 of set 1",
  "description" : "",
  "quantity" : 1.0,
  "price" : 3700.0,
  "total" : 3700.0,
  "tax" : null,
  "discount" : null
} ],

"items" : [ {
  "id" : 288,
  "created" : [ 2016, 5, 26, 5, 29, 51 ],
  "updated" : [ 2016, 5, 27, 0, 31, 11 ],
  "sku" : "JJ-02-00-042",
  "name" : "Product 1 of set 2",
  "description" : "",
  "quantity" : 1.0,
  "price" : 3000.0,
  "total" : 3000.0,
  "tax" : null,
  "discount" : null
} ],

"items" : [ {
  "id" : 310,
  "created" : [ 2016, 5, 30, 7, 40, 41 ],
  "updated" : [ 2016, 5, 30, 7, 40, 46 ],
  "sku" : "J481",
  "name" : "Product 1 set 3",
  "description" : "",
  "quantity" : 1.0,
  "price" : 2200.0,
  "total" : 2200.0,
  "tax" : null,
  "discount" : null
} ],

"items" : [ {
  "id" : 311,
  "created" : [ 2016, 5, 30, 7, 48, 39 ],
  "updated" : [ 2016, 5, 30, 7, 48, 44 ],
  "sku" : "JJ1",
  "name" : "Product 2 set 3",
  "description" : "",
  "quantity" : 1.0,
  "price" : 2200.0,
  "total" : 2200.0,
  "tax" : null,
  "discount" : null
} ],

"items" : [ {
  "id" : 312,
  "created" : [ 2016, 5, 30, 9, 8, 31 ],
  "updated" : [ 2016, 5, 30, 9, 8, 32 ],
  "sku" : "J77",
  "name" : "Product 3 in set 3",
  "description" : "",
  "quantity" : 1.0,
  "price" : 2200.0,
  "total" : 2200.0,
  "tax" : null,
  "discount" : null
} ]
}
]
}
```

As it is now all I can get out of this is the first set of products. What I want to do is get all three sets as well as the "created" field too. I have had no luck getting the created field at all. its just empty.

This is how I have been getting the data out of the json file

```
        for (_, myosin) in newJson["order_history"][0]["items"] {
            if let set = myosin["name"].string {
                //products is a string crated somewhere up there ^
                products.appendContentsOf("\n" + name)
            }

        }
```

Thank you for any help with this.

Comment: Dude there is no name field in the dictionaries of first two items

Comment: I know thats why I don't think this is possible, but I figured I would ask. This is what I was told to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're decoding the "name" field into a `set` variable but then you're trying to use a `name` variable which doesn't exist. You're also using `appendContentsOf` but it should be `append`.

```
var products = [String]()

for (_, myosin) in newJson["order_history"][0]["items"] {
    if let set = myosin["name"].string {
        products.append("\n" + set)
    }
}

print(products)
```

And to get the "created" array for each dictionary:

```
var createdArrays = [[Int]]()

for (_, myosin) in newJson["order_history"][0]["items"] {
    if let created = myosin["created"].arrayObject as? [Int] {
        createdArrays.append(created)
    }
}

print(createdArrays)
```

Comment: Thank you @Eric D I appreciate it. Im still getting use to writing code in swift